# Can I force my old versions of my app users in iOS to update?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, mobile

My app's old versions interfere with my firebase in a way that crashes the app for my newest version
How do I force old versions to stop working?

Comment: By have previously added code that checks your sever for some setting and then display a warning that users need to update. If you never did something like that you can't do anything about it. You can just hope that they will update if their app crashes too often. In general your sever should reject requests that no longer adhere to the internal api / interface you want / have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do anything about versions out there in the wild, but moving forward, you can add version checking to your system (e.g., I generally have a “minimum required” and “latest” version number stored in some configuration resource in my web service) and I have the app check those when it launches. But obviously, this version checking logic is not in the versions already distributed. Just on a “go forward” basis.

An even easier solution is something like [Siren](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren). But, again, this will not help you with versions already out there.

---

If you really have old app that is corrupting database for new releases, you can either

1. Make the new release more tolerant of this old, invalid data; or
2. Make a change in the database that isolates the old app from the new one or simply breaks the old app (e.g. rename some key table that it needs)

I would really advise against the second solution, but sometimes you gotta do what you gotta do.